# Chain rule for a simple function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, chain-rule

I am currently struggling with the chain rule for PDE. Let's suppose that we have a function $u(t,x_1,x_2)$ invariant by translation, i.e. :

$$\forall s, u(t,x_1,x_2) = u(t,x_1+s,x_2+s).$$
I define a new variable $y=x_1-x_2$ and I am interested in the study of the "difference function" defined as :

$$d(t,y) := u(t,0,x1-x2).$$

What would be the derivative $\partial_y d$ of $d$ w.r.t. $y$ ? (A combination of $\partial_{x_1}u$ and $\partial_{x_2}u$ I guess...)

Thank you very much !

Comment: Many letters may cause confusion, when you use them both as variables and as denominators of positions for differentiation. In your case, $y$ should  be both on the left and on the right, and the answer will only consist of $u'_3$ understood as the derivative with respect to the third position.

Comment: Thank you very much @zkutch ! One more question, what would be the same derivative as before if I consider now $d(t,x_1-x_2) = u(t,x_1,x_1-x_2)$ ? (The derivative of $d$ wrt. the variable $x_1-x_2$) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult for me to write this in the comments, so I'm writing here: either you have $y$ and have
$$\frac{\partial d(t,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u(t,0,y)}{\partial y} = u'_3(t,0,y)$$

or you have a complex function $u(t,x_1,x_1-x_2)$ and then
$$\frac{\partial u(t,x_1,x_1-x_2)}{\partial x_1} = u'_2(t,x_1,x_1-x_2)+u'_3(t,x_1,x_1-x_2)$$
$$\frac{\partial u(t,x_1,x_1-x_2)}{\partial x_2}=-u'_3(t,x_1,x_1-x_2)$$

Comment: Thank you very much !